# UIAutomation : Cancel button on Alert view is tapped without actually doing it

Tags: ios, uialertview, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm facing this weird problem in UIAutomation.

I am checking an alert. In that, I am trying to log alert title and alert message. My code for this is:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
UIALogger.logMessage("alert Shown");
UIALogger.logMessage(frontApp.alert().name());
UIALogger.logMessage(frontApp.alert().staticTexts()[1].value());
}

var target = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow();
target.scrollViews()[0].buttons()["saveB"].tap();
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(2);
```

I am not tapping on cancel button in the alert to dismiss it. But, it is getting tapped automatically. I don't know why. Even in the logMessages, I see

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().cancelButton().tap()
```

this line getting executed automatically. I don't have this line anywhere in my script file. Is it a bug in iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cancel button on an alert is always tapped to keep the application from blocking *unless* the `onAlert` callback returns `true`. By returning `true`, you are telling the alert handling mechanism that *you* will handle tapping the appropriate button to dismiss the alert.

Change your alert callback to look like this:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
    UIALogger.logMessage("alert Shown");
    UIALogger.logMessage(frontApp.alert().name());
    UIALogger.logMessage(frontApp.alert().staticTexts()[1].value());
    return true;   // <-- Adding this line
}
```

Conversely, returning `false` or leaving out a return value altogether signals to the alert handling mechanism that the cancel button should be tapped.

Comment: I added this line already but it is not working for me. So I need to type the password on the alert window. I was wondering if I should write the onAlert function first, and then enter the passcode? Or the other way around? Thanks!